# Determining if an IA (Intermediate Authority) SSL certificate has been deployed

Tags: ssl-certificate

I've recently redeployed an IA and normal certificate. Is there a way to check a live domain for whether or not the IA certificate is available?

Comment: What do you mean by "the IA certificate is available"?

Comment: That the IA certificate has been loaded and is being served, properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:443 -servername <hostname>
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you would include some information on what he should do with the output of that.

Comment: I was the OP. The first section returned is called "Certificate chain", and includes a list of all associated certificates, starting with the very specific, all the way to the highest/most general certificate authority.

Comment: Aah, I see.  Answers with nothing but code in them come up in a queue where the context sometimes isn't readily apparent.

Comment: I asked a series of arguably similar questions with different objectives in both SO and ServerFault. By the time I got to this, I had already answered it three other times.